# Count(), max(),min() fuctions definition with many selects

Tags: sql, function, group-by, greatest-n-per-group, min

Lets say we have a view/table `hotel(hotel_n,hotel_name, room_n, price)`. I want to find the cheapest room. I tried `group by room_n`, but I want the hotels name (`hotel_name`) to be shown to the board without grouping it.

So as an amateur with sql(oracle 11g) I began with

```
select hotel_n, room_n, min(price)
from hotel
group by room_n;
```

but it shows the error: `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`. I know I have to type `group by room_n, hotel_n`, but I want the `hotel_n` to be seen in the table that I make without grouping by it!

Any ideas? thank you very much!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be helpful.  I'm guessing you want to get the min price in a subquery and join back to the main table to get matching hotels...

Comment: It will be good to state what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aggregate functions are useful to show, well, aggregate information per group of rows. If you want to get a specific row from a group of rows in relation to the other group members (e.g., the cheapest room per `room_n`), you'd probably need an analytic function, such as [`rank`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions155.htm#SQLRF00690):

```
SELECT hotel_n, hotel_name, room_n, price
FROM   (SELECT hotel_n, hotel_name, room_n, price
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY room_n ORDER BY price ASC) rk
        FROM   hotel) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: God why it has to be that complicate?! thanks man I will try to learn that rank funcion.